# Unexpected token error with simple paperscript animation

Tags: javascript, animation, token

I've been trying to create a simple two ball simulation with paperscript in an html file. The two balls animate and bounce around inside the browser window as expected. But, when I tried to insert the if statement: if(((xPos2-xPos1)**2+(yPos2-yPos1)**2)**0.5<=100) in the code shown below the  animation disappears and instead an 'unexpected token' error appears in the chrome console. I'm trying to insert some very basic collision event into the code but getting nowhere. Any ideas what the problem could be?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ball Animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ballAnimation.css">
    <!-- Load the Paper.js library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="paper-full.js"></script>
    <!-- Define inlined PaperScript associate it with myCanvas -->
    <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">



        // }

        var xPos1 = 100;
        var yPos1 = 100;
        var xPos2 = 100;
        var yPos2 = 100;
        var xInc1 = 10;
        var yInc1 = 12;
        var xInc2 = -10;
        var yInc2 = 20;
        var circle2 = new Path.Circle(new Point(100, 70), 50);
        circle2.fillColor = 'purple';
        var circle3 = new Path.Circle(new Point(250, 120), 50);
        circle3.fillColor = 'yellow';
        function onFrame(){
            if(xPos1>=1000 || xPos1 <= 0){
                xInc1 = (-1)*xInc1;
            }
            if(yPos1>=680 || yPos1<=0){
                yInc1 = (-1)*yInc1;
            }
            xPos1 += xInc1;
            yPos1 += yInc1;
            if(xPos2>=1000 || xPos2 <= 0){
                xInc2 = (-1)*xInc2;
            }
            if(yPos2>=680 || yPos2<=0){
                yInc2 = (-1)*yInc2;
            }

            if(((xPos2-xPos1)**2+(yPos2-yPos1)**2)**0.5<=100) {
                xInc1 = (-1)*xInc1;
                yInc1 = (-1)*yInc1;
                xInc2 = (-1)*xInc2;
                yInc2 = (-1)*yInc2;
            }

            xPos2 += xInc2;
            yPos2 += yInc2;
            circle2.position += [xInc1,yInc1];
            circle3.position += [xInc2,yInc2];
        }



    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" resize="true"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help. 
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

The exponentiation operator `**` doesn't have great support in today's popular browsers.

You should use `Math.pow(x, n)` instead of `x**n`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ball Animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ballAnimation.css">
    <!-- Load the Paper.js library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.10.3/paper-full.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Define inlined PaperScript associate it with myCanvas -->
    <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">


        var xPos1 = 100;
        var yPos1 = 100;
        var xPos2 = 100;
        var yPos2 = 100;
        var xInc1 = 10;
        var yInc1 = 12;
        var xInc2 = -10;
        var yInc2 = 20;
        var circle2 = new Path.Circle(new Point(100, 70), 50);
        circle2.fillColor = 'purple';
        var circle3 = new Path.Circle(new Point(250, 120), 50);
        circle3.fillColor = 'yellow';
        function onFrame(){
            if(xPos1>=1000 || xPos1 <= 0){
                xInc1 = (-1)*xInc1;
            }
            if(yPos1>=680 || yPos1<=0){
                yInc1 = (-1)*yInc1;
            }
            xPos1 += xInc1;
            yPos1 += yInc1;
            if(xPos2>=1000 || xPos2 <= 0){
                xInc2 = (-1)*xInc2;
            }
            if(yPos2>=680 || yPos2<=0){
                yInc2 = (-1)*yInc2;
            }

            if(Math.pow(Math.pow(xPos2-xPos1,2)+Math.pow(yPos2-yPos1,2),0.5)<=100) {
                xInc1 = (-1)*xInc1;
                yInc1 = (-1)*yInc1;
                xInc2 = (-1)*xInc2;
                yInc2 = (-1)*yInc2;
            }

            xPos2 += xInc2;
            yPos2 += yInc2;
            circle2.position += [xInc1,yInc1];
            circle3.position += [xInc2,yInc2];
        }



    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" resize="true"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```